# How to sorting strings in unicode using a predefined alphabet?

Tags: php, sorting, unicode, multibyte-functions, multibyte-characters

I have a mysql table with words in unicode using signs like `ḥ`, `ḫ` `š`, etc.
The columns in the table are defined as `utf8mb4_general_ci` and recognize the above signs.

In the header of the webpage I put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8mb4">
```

This webpage contains a form sending data to a php page. In the beginning of the php page I put:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8mb4");
```

In this page, I do a mysql search and I get an array and it is this array (`$result`) must be sorted by its keys using a lookup array of characters that I have produced which includes single and multi-byte characters.

This is the array:

```
Array ( 
[nṯr] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176b [1] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1 ) 
[n] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c [1] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1 [2] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2 ) 
[nḫȝḫȝ] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c ) 
[nwj] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c ) 
[nfr] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c [1] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2 ) 
[nḥḥ] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176e [1] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1 [2] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1 ) 
[nḏ] => Array ( [0] => Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1 ) 
)
```

What I do is:

```
uksort($result, 'compare_keys_by_alphabet');
```

This refers to the function:

```
function compare_keys_by_alphabet($a, $b)
{
    static $alphabet = array( 1 => "-" , 2 => "," , 3 => ".", 4 => "ȝ", 5 => "j", 6 => "ʿ", 7 => "w", 8 => "b", 9 => "p", 10 => "f", 11 => "m", 12 => "n", 13 => "r", 14 => "h", 15 => "ḥ", 16 => "ḫ", 17 => "ẖ", 18 => "s", 19 => "š", 20 => "q", 21 => "k", 22 => "g", 23 => "t", 24 => "ṯ", 25 => "d", 26 => "ḏ", 27 => "⸗", 28 => "/", 29 => "(", 30 => ")", 31 => "[", 32 => "]", 33 => "<", 34 => ">", 35 => "{", 36 => "}", 37 => "'", 38 => "*", 39 => "#", 40 => "I", 41 => "0", 42 => "1", 43 => "2", 44 => "3", 45 => "4", 46 => "5", 47 => "6", 48 => "7", 49 => "8", 50 => "9", 51 => "&", 52 => "@", 53 => "%");

    return compare_by_alphabet($alphabet, $a, $b);
}
```

using:

```
function compare_by_alphabet(array $alphabet, $str1, $str2) {
    $c = max(strlen($str1), strlen($str2));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $s1 = $str1[$i];
        $s2 = $str2[$i];
        //if ($s1===$s2) continue;
        $i1 = array_search($s1, $alphabet);
        //if ($i1===false) continue;
        $i2 = array_search($s2, $alphabet);
        //sif ($i2===false) continue;
        if ($i2==$i1) continue;
        if ($i1 < $i2) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This worked perfect with the non-unicode alphabet:

```
static $alphabet2 = array( 1 => '-' , 2 => ',' , 3 => '.' , 4 => "A", 5 => "j", 6 => "a", 7 => "w", 8 => "b", 9 => "p", 10 => "f", 11 => "m", 12 => "n", 13 => "r", 14 => "h", 15 => "H", 16 => "x", 17 => "X", 18 => "s", 19 => "S", 20 => "q", 21 => "k", 22 => "g", 23 => "t", 24 => "T", 25 => "d", 26 => "D", 27 => "=", 28 => "/", 29 => "(", 30 => ")", 31 => "[", 32 => "]", 33 => "<", 34 => ">", 35 => "{", 36 => "}", 37 => "'", 38 => "*", 39 => "#", 40 => "I", 41 => "1", 42 => "2", 43 => "3", 44 => "4", 45 => "5", 46 => "6", 47 => "7", 48 => "8", 49 => "9", 50 => "0", 51 => "&", 52 => "@", 53 => "%");
```

but once I replaced for example `H` (nr 15) in alphabet2 with `ḥ` in alphabet1 it didn't work anymore.

I suppose it has to do with recognizing the unicode, because as long as the words do not contain any special signs, the order is correct; but all words containing special signs are put at the beginning of the result.

I tried to look at unicode normalization; but I'm really only an amateur, so this is quite difficult.

Is this the problem or is there another problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've left all of my testing echoes in my code block and merely commented them out in case you wanted to see what is being generated throughout the process.

I took some liberties with your code.  I didn't like the function calling the function, and I condensed your lookup array into a space-led string.  This will serve to have the same effect as your indexed array that starts from 1.  The converting of the lookup from array to string means I can use `mb_strpos()` instead of `array_search()`.

The crucial point to fix in your code was in the looping, specifically accessing the letters with `[$i]`.  You see, you cannot treat these multibyte characters as single byte characters -- you must use `mb_substr()` to access the "whole" letter.

Setting values for `$alphabet` and `encoding` means, you don't have to write a second "helper" function to pass all of the necessary data.  `uksort()` will pass its expected two arguments and everything goes ahead smoothly.

One final piece of advice is: `mb_` functions are expensive, so always try to `return` in your code as soon as possible and leave the `mb_` functions farther "downscript" whenever logically possible.

Here is my suggested code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MhiVJ))

```
function alphabetize_custom($a, $b, $alphabet = " -,.ȝjʿwbpfmnrhḥḫẖsšqkgtṯdḏ⸗/()[]<>{}'*#I0123456789&@%", $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    //echo "\n----\n$a =vs= $b";
    $mb_length = max(mb_strlen($a, $encoding), mb_strlen($b, $encoding));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $mb_length; ++$i) {
        //echo "\n";
        $a_char = mb_substr($a, $i, 1, $encoding);
        $b_char = mb_substr($b, $i, 1, $encoding);
        //echo "$a_char -vs- $b_char\n";
        //echo "(" , mb_strlen($a_char, $encoding), " & ", mb_strlen($b_char, $encoding), ")\n";
        if ($a_char === $b_char) {/*echo "identical, continue";*/ continue;}
        if (!mb_strlen($a_char, $encoding)) { /* echo "a is empty -1";*/ return -1;}
        if (!mb_strlen($b_char, $encoding)) { /*echo "b is empty 1";*/ return 1;}
        $a_offset = mb_strpos($alphabet, $a_char, 0, $encoding);
        $b_offset = mb_strpos($alphabet, $b_char, 0, $encoding);
        //echo "[" , $a_offset, " & ", $b_offset, "]\n";
        if ($a_offset == $b_offset) { /*echo "== offsets, continue";*/ continue;}
        if ($a_offset < $b_offset) { /*echo "a offset -1";*/ return -1;}
        //echo "b offset 1";
        return 1;
    }
    //echo "0";
    return 0;
}

$result = [
    "nṯr" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176b", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"],
    "n" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2"],
    "nḫȝḫȝ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c"],
    "nwj" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c"],
    "nfr" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2"],
    "nḥḥ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176e", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"],
    "nḏ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"]
];

uksort($result, 'alphabetize_custom');

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'n' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c',
    1 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1',
    2 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2',
  ),
  'nwj' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c',
  ),
  'nfr' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c',
    1 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2',
  ),
  'nḥḥ' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176e',
    1 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1',
    2 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1',
  ),
  'nḫȝḫȝ' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c',
  ),
  'nṯr' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176b',
    1 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1',
  ),
  'nḏ' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1',
  ),
)
```

---

Just for comparison's sake, I wrote an alternative code block that uses `array_search()` as your original code does and not surprisingly it appears to be more efficient according to the speed tests on 3v4l.org.  This is likely due to the removal of a couple of 4 `mb_` functions, which I previously mentioned to be "expensive".  The following snippet provides the same output.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3XYNG))

```
function alphabetize_custom($a, $b) {
    $alphabet = [' ', '-', ',', '.', 'ȝ', 'j', 'ʿ', 'w', 'b', 'p', 'f', 'm', 'n', 'r', 'h', 'ḥ', 'ḫ', 'ẖ', 's', 'š', 'q', 'k', 'g', 't', 'ṯ', 'd', 'ḏ', '⸗', '/', '(', ')', '[', ']', '<', '>', '{', '}', "'", '*', '#', 'I', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '&', '@', '%'];
    unset($alphabet[0]);  // removes dummy first key, effectively starting the keys from 1
    $encoding = 'UTF-8';

    $mb_length = max(mb_strlen($a, $encoding), mb_strlen($b, $encoding));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $mb_length; ++$i) {
        $a_char = mb_substr($a, $i, 1, $encoding);
        $b_char = mb_substr($b, $i, 1, $encoding);
        if ($a_char === $b_char) continue;

        $a_key = array_search($a_char, $alphabet);
        $b_key = array_search($b_char, $alphabet);
        if ($a_key === $b_key) continue;

        return $a_key - $b_key;
    }
    return 0;
}

$result = [
    "nṯr" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176b", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"],
    "n" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2"],
    "nḫȝḫȝ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c"],
    "nwj" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c"],
    "nfr" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176c", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,2"],
    "nḥḥ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,176e", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1", "Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"],
    "nḏ" => ["Ka.C.Coptite.urkVIII,177,1"]
];

uksort($result, 'alphabetize_custom');

var_export($result);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for introducing me to the mb_ functions.

Comment: @Preys I was thinking about my posted code block and realized I could produce a better version.  I recommend using this instead of my first attempt.  If you don't mind the `$alphabet` syntax being long, you can spare the `unset()` call and just declare the array as you have originally.

Answer (score 0):

The `charset` in the `meta` tag needs to be `UTF-8`.  That is what the outside world calls it; MySQL calls it `utf8mb4`.

Inside MySQL, declare the collation of the columns you want to be ordered with `COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  With that, MySQL can do the work for you:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY col ...
```